# How to get the multiple values of similar tags using Pattern Matching in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

For example,

say string is "-u xyz -p 1234 -z ask -p secure -o all -p demo"

I would like to get match all the occurrences of -p and get the values of it,

I tried but it only gives stops at the first match,

```
$command =~ /(.*)\-p\s+(.*?)\s+(.*)/g;
print $2
```

which will result in

`1234`

Any idea, how can I recur it and get all the values: 1234, secure, demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for the example:

```
$command = "-u xyz -p 1234 -z ask -p secure -o all -p demo";

while($command =~ /\-p ([^ ]+)/g) {
  print "$1\n";
}
```

result:

```
1234
secure
demo
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to parse command line options.  If so, use the standard Getopt::Long module that comes with Perl.

http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html

No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Hi, Its not a command line argument but a string which comes from a flat file, which I read through in my perl script and I need to get all the values of a specific tags...

Comment: Even though it's not command line arguments, I bet you could still use Getopt::Long for the task.  It certainly seems that those tags are supposed to look like command arguments, no?

Comment: Yes this is a command line arguments but is coming from a flat file as a string, can we use Getopt::Long to read tags from a string ?

Comment: Yes.  See ["Parsing options from an arbitrary string"](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Parsing-options-from-an-arbitrary-string)